# Laravel 5 Inverse of belongsToMany

Tags: php, laravel

actually not sure if I am doing it correctly or there are other ways. What I have in my database are the following

```
brands
    id: integer
    name: string
    slug: string
    description: string
    timestamp

products
    id: integer
    name: string
    price: decimal
    slug: string
    description: string
    timestamp

brand_product
    id: integer
    brand_id: unsignedInteger
    product_id: unsignedInteger
```

Basically, brands have many products, so on my Brand model

```
...
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
...
```

However, a Product has one (1) Brand model. Pretty sure I can achieve what I want by adding `brand_id` on my `products` table and do the relationship thing on my Product model. However, I have an above database structure. What I did, on my Product model:

```
...
protected $appends = ['brand'];

public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class);
}

public function getBrandAttribute()
{
    return $this->brand()->first();
}
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption of adding a `brand_id` on products is correct. What you are describing is a one-to-many relationship, but a database structure representing a many-to-many. Remove the pivot table and add the brand id to the products table and you'll be good to go.

```
// Product model
public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
}

// Brand model
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would be to remove the pivot table and define a one-to-many relation.

However, if you have to keep the schema with the pivot table, you just simply put the belongsToMany() on both of your models. There is no specific inverse of belongsToMany() in Laravel.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code inside your Product model:

```
public function brands()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Brand', 'brand_product');
}
```

Now you can get the first row of the brands of the product by using the following code in your controller:

```
$product->brands()->get()->first(); // Will return the first row
```